# Integracion con woocommerce no muestra mercadopago como opcion de pago

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, mercadopago

integré woocommerce en un sitio wordpress. Tengo configurada la moneda peso argentino, tengo los tokens de MP de produccion y de prueba configurados. Me aparecen las opciones de mercadopago en la seccion de pago en configuracion de woocommerce.

El problema es que al momento de realizar una compra y darle finalizar pedido, no se muestran las opciones de mercadopago. Transferencia es la unica que se muestra y si la deshabilito no se muestra ninguna opción.

**Información del sitio:**

```
- Tiene certificado SSL

WordPress 6.4.2 funciona con el tema JNews.

Server running PHP version: 7.4.33. MySQL version: 10.6.16-MariaDB
```

[image: imagen de finalizacion de compra]

Por que no se muestran las opciones?